# Swift Linux Generate Random Bool

Tags: linux, swift, server-side-swift

I am trying to make a static extension of `Bool` to return a random true/false value whenever called. I am trying to make this work:

```
static func coinFlip() -> Bool {
    #if os(Linux)
    srand(UInt32(time(nil)))
    let result = Int(random() % 2)
    if result == 0 {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
    #else
    return arc4random_uniform(2) == 0
    #endif
}
```

I am using this within the scope of a route being called in a Server Side Swift application. Whenever it is called for the first time, it does return a random value, but all subsequent calls to the function in the same scope don't randomize the output. For example:

```
for _ in 1...5 {
    let coin = Bool.coinFlip()
    if coin == true {
        print("coin flip true")
    } else {
        print("coin flip false")
    }
}
```

...yields an output of this:

```
coin flip false
coin flip false
coin flip false
coin flip false
coin flip false
```

...but then if I call the route again separately, I could get:

```
coin flip true
coin flip true
coin flip true
coin flip true
coin flip true
```

Is it a problem with `srand(UInt32(time(nil)))` only randomizing the pseudo-random sequence of `random()`? I'm not sure what to do. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time(nil))` returns the current time as a number of *seconds,* which means that
you seed the random number generator with the *same value* when
the method is called multiple times within a one second interval.

You should call `srand(UInt32(time(nil)))` only once on application
startup, not on each call of `coinFlip()`.

In addition, the function can be simplified a bit, and I would call
it `random()`, not `coinFlip()`:

```
#if os(Linux)
    srand(UInt32(time(nil)))
#endif

extension Bool {
    static func random() -> Bool {
        #if os(Linux)
            return Glibc.random() % 2 == 0
        #else
            return arc4random_uniform(2) == 0
        #endif
    }
}

for _ in 1...5 {
    print(Bool.random())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Swift 4.2, there is a native way to do this:

```
let flippedCoin = Bool.random()
```

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bool/2994861-random